# Seeding rails app with a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding

Trying to create a seed for the last 5 hours((... Please help if You have any ideas, Since I am  new to Rails my seeds seem very wrong... You can see all my files here:

my user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :recipes
end
```

my recipe.rb :

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :directions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients,
                              reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? },
                              allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :directions,
                              reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['step'].blank? },
                              allow_destroy: true

  validates :title, :description, :image, presence: true
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "400x400#" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

my ingredient.rb:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

my direction.rb:

```
class Direction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

my schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150721133516) do

 create_table "directions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "step"
    t.integer  "recipe_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end

 add_index "directions", ["recipe_id"], name: "index_directions_on_recipe_id"

 create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.integer  "recipe_id"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end

 add_index "ingredients", ["recipe_id"], name: "index_ingredients_on_recipe_id"

 create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "title"
   t.text     "description"
   t.integer  "user_id"
   t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
   t.string   "image_file_name"
   t.string   "image_content_type"
   t.integer  "image_file_size"
   t.datetime "image_updated_at"
 end

 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
   t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
   t.string   "reset_password_token"
   t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
   t.datetime "remember_created_at"
   t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
   t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
   t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
   t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
   t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
   t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
 end

 add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
 add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

and my try to create a seeds.rb:

```
r1 = Recipe.create(
title: "Red, White and Blue Poke Cake", 
description: "Red, white and beautiful! A simple cake-mix cake becomes the hit of your Fourth of July gathering with just a few easy additions.", 
image: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/gmi-digital-library/665dd965-1b01-46ea-8f32-4b745b037817.jpg",
user_id: "1",
image_file_name: "name",
image_content_type: "/\Aimage\/.*\Z/",
image_file_size: "400x400#",
 )

r1.ingredients.create(name: "1
box Betty Crocker™ SuperMoist™ white cake mix
Water, vegetable oil and egg whites called for on cake mix box
1
box (4-serving size) strawberry-flavored gelatin
1 cup milk", recipe_id: r1.id )
r1.directions.create(step: "1 Heat oven to 350°F (325°F for dark or    nonstick pan). Make and bake cake mix as directed on box for 13x9-inch pan. Cool completely in pan, about 1 hour.
2 Pierce cooled cake with fork at 1/2-inch intervals. In medium bowl, stir gelatin and boiling water until dissolved. Stir in cold water. Carefully pour mixture over entire surface of cake. Refrigerate at least 3 hours until serving time.
3 In large bowl, mix pudding mix and milk until well blended. Gently stir in whipped topping. Spread over cake. Arrange strawberries and blueberries on top of cake to look like flag. Store loosely covered in refrigerator.",
recipe_id: r1.id )
```

Comment: What error are you getting post it?